# increase DPI of x11() canvas in R

Tags: linux, r

Is it possible to increase the dpi of images displayed by the `x11()` device in R? By default, my plots are very grainy.

Comment: I've tried using the Cairo canvas, but it consistently crashes my R instance.

Comment: What are you trying to do that you care that your plots are grainy? For interactive use, grainy plots can be annoying but isn't a big deal. If you're wanting to save the images use `pdf(...) <plot stuff> dev.off()` [or `jpeg()`, see `?jpeg` for more file options] or  `ggsave` if you're using `ggplot2`. Also, my Linux machine is at home, otherwise, I'd fire up `R` and try to help you more.

Comment: For interactive exploration of my data with  people I work with who aren't familiar with R, I'd rather not show them terrible quality plots, especially when one of my selling points for using R rather than SAS/JMP/Excel is that R has higher quality graphics.

Comment: That's a very good reason. Perhaps checkout [RStudio](http://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/). It has its own plot viewing challenges, but might look better. It's worth a shot. Also, flavor of Linux are you using? That might help somebody else with your question. I don't know how to solve your problem. My last tip would be to wait a few days and post this question to the [Linux and Unix](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) stack as an X11 question if you don't hear from anyone.

Comment: I use CentOS version 6 at work and Arch Linux at home and my `x11` plots look equally grainy on both operating systems.

Comment: I found this thread suggesting that perhaps I need the pangocairo command to be available: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/cairo-is-not-the-default-when-available-td4666691.html